# How can I check to see if the active window is maximized with vbs?

Tags: vbscript

When I'm working, I want to be able to maximize or restore a window.  But I only want to use one shortcut key to do it.  I am currently using the below code to perform the function of maximizing.  However, if the window is already maximized, this won't 'restore' the window.

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.SendKeys "% x"
```

I guess I'm thinking of code like this:

```
if window state=Maximized 
then Restore
else Maximize
```

This logic will 'maximize' the window if it isn't and 'restore' it if it is.

Thanks.

PS: Extra points if you skip the whole SendKeys thing and go straight to native commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript and Windows Script Host don't provide access to Windows API, so you can't do that.

A possible workaround is to write a custom utility (in C++, C# with PInvoke etc) that will perform this kind of check and call it from your script.